# How to find the next select dropdown nested inside an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find the next select dropdown nested inside another div.

I've tried a few different ways But my code always returns undefined for some reason.

Reason for this is to change the value of next dropdown if certain values are selected in the first select dropdown.

**This is my code:**

```js
$(document).on('change', '.from select', function(e) {
  console.log($(this).closest('div.to').next('.smallSelect').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hours" id="">

  <div class="from">
    <select class="smallSelect">
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option value="CLOSED">CLOSED</option>
      <option value="00:00">12.00 AM</option>
      <option value="00:30">12.30 AM</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="to">
    <select class="smallSelect">
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option value="CLOSED">CLOSED</option>
      <option value="00:00">12.00 AM</option>
      <option value="00:30">12.30 AM</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

could someone please advice on this issue?

I have also tried this which did not work:

```
$(this).parents(".to").find(".select").val();
```

Comment: `.closest()` traverses upwards. Because your `select` is not a descendant of `.to`, `.closest()` will not find it. Instead, find the first common parent (`"hours"`), and then look for the select within it: `$(this).closest("div.hours").find(".to select")` for example.

Comment: Side note: I've reduced the amount of `<option>`s in your example, just for sake of brevity.

Comment: @TylerRoper, that did it and thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your change handler is binding to the select element, so you need to up the DOM to the `.from` div, then to the `.to` div next sibling, then down to the select via:

```
$(this).parent().next().find('.smallSelect').val()
```

```js
$(document).on('change', '.from select', function(e) {
  console.log($(this).parent().next().find('.smallSelect').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hours" id="">

  <div class="from">
    <select class="smallSelect">
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option value="CLOSED">CLOSED</option>
      <option value="00:00">12.00 AM</option>
      <option value="00:30">12.30 AM</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="to">
    <select class="smallSelect">
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option value="CLOSED">CLOSED</option>
      <option value="00:00">12.00 AM</option>
      <option value="00:30">12.30 AM</option>
    </select>
  </div>

</div>
```